# how do I implement calendar with primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I have an output label and inputText and I want to implement calendar but when i put it,
   it doesn't work

```
            <p:outputLabel value="Date " for="datem" />

           <p:inputText id="datem" value="# {bean.datem}"title="date" >
                 <f:convertDateTime pattern="d-M-yyyy" />
                </p:inputText>
```

Comment: Check the showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml

Comment: I found the prolème .. it was a script that was blocking the calendar display